# Modify the user data stdObject and add extra items to it?

Tags: users

Is it possible to add another item to this `data` object without using `user_meta`?

I would like to just add one more item to this standard class object.

The item I want to add is `[user_tel]` below the `[user_email]`.

```
[data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [user_login] => josh
            [user_pass] => $P$BKeFc3LoEr3njndyv7b/SlLkvPZ.
            [user_nicename] => josh
            [user_email] => josh@domain.com
            [user_tel] => +44 (0) 7000 000 000
            [user_url] => 
            [user_registered] => 2018-11-08 20:05:34
            [user_activation_key] => 
            [user_status] => 0
            [display_name] => Josh Cranwell
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Not without modifying core tables, which is a bad idea. Info like this belongs in meta.

Comment: OK cool thanks for the tip, I was not sure if was bad practice or not. But yeah it makes sense, i've gone with the meta option. Cheers